# Updated: Frullani Integral For $0<a , b< \infty$, show $\int^\infty_0 \ \frac{|\sin(bx)|-|\sin(ax)|}{x} dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\ln(\frac{b}{a})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For $0<a , b< \infty$, show $$\int^\infty_0 \ \frac{|\sin(bx)|-|\sin(ax)|}{x} dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\ln(\frac{b}{a})$$

I this can be written as $$\int^\infty_0 \ \frac{|f(bx)|-|f(ax)|}{x}=M(f)\ln(\frac{b}{a}) dx$$ as this is just a slight transformation from the original formula that is given in my book $$I(a,b) = \int^\infty_0 \ \frac{f(bx)-f(ax)}{x} dx = M(f)\ln(\frac{b}{a}) \text{                               where     } 0<a , b< \infty$$

From here I say $\int^\pi_0|\sin(x)|dx=2 f(0)=0$ and by L'Hopital's rule $\frac{f(x)}{x}=0.$ Therefore $M(f)=\frac{2}{\pi}$ Plug that in and we get the desired answer.

However, I think I've made an error here because the second part of the question asks the same thing except with $\cos$ this time and I get the same answer using my method but it should be $(\frac{2}{\pi}-1)\ln(\frac{b}{a})$

Update: Actually it is $M(f):=\lim \frac{1}{x} \int^x_0 f(t)dt$ We use pi for both sin and cos and if you plug the f(t) into Mathematica you'll find f(t)=2 for both of them in this case. This is why I'm very confused.

Comment: Limit as $x\to$? I misread the value of the integral. There should be a "," between 2 and $f(0)$.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, is this a question or a statement?

Comment: A question. You do not say i f$x$ approaches $0$, $\infty$ or any othe value.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your book defines $M(f)$. It should be
$$
M(f)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)-\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)
$$
if both limits exist. But in your problem neither $\lim_{x\to\infty}|\sin x|$ nor $\lim_{x\to\infty}|\cos x|$ exist. In those cases, another definition of $M(f)$ is useful:
$$
M(f)=\lim_{x\to0}x\int_x^1\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\,dt-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_1^x\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt.
$$
Using this definition you will get
$$
M(|\sin|)=0,\quad M(|\cos|)=1.
$$

Comment: Your definition of $M(f)$ is not the same as my books. I've updated my question to include my books definition!